# I want to store values in file in json format using fs

Tags: node.js, json, testing, automation, fs

```
            let AccountDetails = {
                dformat,
                username,
                password, 
                accountType,
                charity
            
        };
        AccountDetails.dformat
            let creds = JSON.stringify(AccountDetails);
            fs.appendFile("LoginID\\JsonCreds.json",creds,(err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    // Get the file contents after the append operation
                    console.log("\nFile Contents of file after append:",
                        fs.readFileSync("LoginID\\JsonCreds.json", "utf8"));
                }
            });
```

```
Output:-{
    "dformat": "2021-12-09 10:09:53","username": "An191428","password": "Root@123","accountType": "Basic Enterprise Postpaid","charity": "Non-charity"
}
```

I want output to be like:-2021-12-09 10:09:53|An191428|Root@123|Basic Enterprise Postpaid|Non-charity
like this and also want new line after every append , please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The o/p you are showing is not JSON, check [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) what is valid json. You can write this data to text file instead of JSON. First of all, you need to get values and create a string with same format and write it to text file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
  let AccountDetails = {
                dformat,
                username,
                password, 
                accountType,
                charity
            
};

const dataFormatted = Object.values(AccountDetails).join('|');

fs.writeFile('create Text file', dataFormatted, {flag: 'a+'}, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
})
```

You can also check [this](https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs) link, how to write to files in Node.js. When you read the text file, create a readLine interface and read line by line and filter out the result.

Comment: ok , i only want to append , because write will overwrite every time i execute.

Comment: Flag- a+ will take the stream position to the end and append from there. You jaut need to make sure file exist and the path is correct.

Comment: Hope this answer helps.

Comment: and like you said , it's not json , how can i store the same values in json?

Comment: These are the values - `2021-12-09 10:09:53|An191428|Root@123|Basic Enterprise Postpaid|Non-charity`, they should be a key value pairs instead and stringify them and save it to JSON.

Comment: you will not be able to use `.appendFile` and maintain JSON in the file.  JSON is a document format, and you will need to be able to wrap all your data in an overall structure.  You might have to read whole file, add in data, and write it out, and be careful if more than one thing is writing concurrently